# Return result by reference in C++

Tags: c++, reference, return, operator-overloading, this

I was practicing something in C++, and I ran into a task which I can solve, but I was curious about this code below. I don't know why we return our values by reference in these two functions:

```
fraction& operator+=(fraction);
fraction& operator++();
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class fraction
{
private:
    int br;
    int im;
public:
    fraction(int=0,int=1);
    fraction& operator+=(fraction);
    fraction& operator++();
    fraction operator++(int);
    void print(){cout<<br<<"/"<<im<<endl;}
};

fraction::fraction(int a,int b):br(a),im(b){}

fraction& fraction::operator+=(fraction r)
{
    br = br*r.im + im*r.br;
    im = im*r.im;
    return *this;
}

fraction& fraction::operator++()
{
    return (*this)+=1;
}

fraction fraction::operator++(int i)
{
    fraction pom(*this);
    (*this)+=1;
    return pom;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Type in the values for fractions"<<endl;
    int b,i;
    cin>>b>>i;
    fraction r1(b,i);
    cin>>b>>i;
    fraction r2(b,i);
    r1+=(r2++);
    r1.print();
}
```

Then I tried to remove the `&` in these functions, and that code also worked fine:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class fraction
{
private:
    int br;
    int im;
public:
    fraction(int=0,int=1);
    fraction operator+=(fraction);
    fraction operator++();
    fraction operator++(int);
    void print(){cout<<br<<"/"<<im<<endl;}
};

fraction::fraction(int a,int b):br(a),im(b){}

fraction fraction::operator+=(fraction r)
{
    br = br*r.im + im*r.br;
    im = im*r.im;
    return *this;
}

fraction fraction::operator++()
{
    return (*this)+=1;
}

fraction fraction::operator++(int i)
{
    fraction pom(*this);
    (*this)+=1;
    return pom;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Type in the values for fractions"<<endl;
    int b,i;
    cin>>b>>i;
    fraction r1(b,i);
    cin>>b>>i;
    fraction r2(b,i);
    r1+=(r2++);
    r1.print();
}
```

So, my question is, why do we use `&` in the first code?

Also, I would appreciate if you could tell me why this code doesn't work. It's a combination of the two codes above, where I removed `&` only from one function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class fraction
{
private:
    int br;
    int im;
public:
    fraction(int=0,int=1);
    fraction operator+=(fraction);
    fraction& operator++();
    fraction operator++(int);
    void print(){cout<<br<<"/"<<im<<endl;}
};

fraction::fraction(int a,int b):br(a),im(b){}

fraction fraction::operator+=(fraction r)
{
    br = br*r.im + im*r.br;
    im = im*r.im;
    return *this;
}

fraction& fraction::operator++()
{
    return (*this)+=1;
}

fraction fraction::operator++(int i)
{
    fraction pom(*this);
    (*this)+=1;
    return pom;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Type in the values for fractions"<<endl;
    int b,i;
    cin>>b>>i;
    fraction r1(b,i);
    cin>>b>>i;
    fraction r2(b,i);
    r1+=(r2++);
    r1.print();
}
```

Sorry for the noob questions, but I just started practicing in C++, and I spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Returning by value would mean making unnecessary copies. Also, one could write things like `(++x) = 10`, which is silly, but it works for `int`, and the convention for overloaded operators is "do what `ints` do".

Comment: So that `a += b += c;` would work. By the way, you included way too much code which is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @DeiDei I don't think `a += b += c` requires `operator+=` to return by reference. `(a += b) += c` would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, my question is, why do we use `&` in the first code?

`&` are used for performance and conformance reasons.
Both operators (pre-increment operator `++` and assignment operator`+=`) from their assumption modify provided value. E.g.:

```
int i=5;
std::cout << ++i; // This will print 6. Notice there is no more value 5, even here
std::cout << i;   // This will print 6 also.
```

Since the original value is lost, there is no point for creating new object and destroy current one. Just current object can be reused for providing new value.

I would recommend looking into reference when overloading operators, since it is easy to create own version that has performance loss or doesn't work with const objects. Here are some links.

- [Increment/decrement operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec)
- [Assignment operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment)
- [Arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

> Also, I would appreciate if you could tell me why this code doesn't work. It's a combination of the two codes above, where I removed & only from one function.

This one is a little more tricky.
If you take closer look at the code from third example:

```
fraction fraction::operator+=(fraction r)
{
    br = br*r.im + im*r.br;
    im = im*r.im;
    return *this;
}

fraction& fraction::operator++()
{
    return (*this)+=1;
}
```

You will notice that `operator++` is using `operator+=` inside.
In fact `operator++` is returning what `operator+=` returns, so `operator++` is returning reference to local `fraction` object that is destroyed when `operator++` ends. You get reference to just destroyed object. This is bad and this is reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: As you know, the semantics of postincrement `r++` are tricky, because you have to copy and then return the original value. But you don’t want to violate the expectations of duck-typed code. It’s almost always more efficient to use `++r`.